# NODEJS/socket.io emit not fired

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

This should be simple, but for some reason my socket.emit will not execute on button press. I know the sumbit button event listener is working. What am I missing?

index.js

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){  
  io.on('pw', function(data){
    console.log(data)
  });
});
```

index.html

```
var submit = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]')
  submit.addEventListener('click',function(){
     socket.emit('pw', 'pw', function(){
       console.log('clicked')
     })
    },false)
```

Comment: `socket.on("pw")`, not `io.on("pw")`. `io` doesn't have `"pw"` events; `socket` has whatever events you throw at it. (I'll see if I can find a duplicate.)

Comment: there probably is one... I'll look too [there are a bunch but I can't find one with my specific mistake]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **socket**.on() other than io.on()

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){  
       socket.on('pw', function(data){
          console.log(data)
       });
   });
```